# How to generate the columns based on the unique values of that particular column in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe as below

```
+----------+------------+---------------------+
|CustomerNo|size        |total_items_purchased|
+----------+------------+---------------------+
|  208261.0|          A |                    2|
|  208263.0|          C |                    1|
|  208261.0|          E |                    1|
|  208262.0|          B |                    2|
|  208264.0|          D |                    3|
+----------+------------+---------------------+
```

I have another table **df** that consists of customerNo's only. I have to create columns of unique comfortStyles and have to update the total_items_purchased in **df**

My df table should look like

```
CustomerNo,size_A,size_B,size_C,size_D,size_E
208261.0     1      0      0      0    1
208262.0     0      2      0      0    0
208263.0     0      0      1      0    0
208264.0     0      0      0      3    0
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pivot` function to rearrange the table.

```py
df = (df.groupBy('CustomerNo')
      .pivot('size')
      .agg(F.first('total_items_purchased'))
      .na.fill(0))
```